# SQL Server service broker and SqlDependency

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a system where my TCP/IP command prompt application receive data and insert that data in `[database1].[mytable]`

Now I want to move that data from `[database1].[mytable]` to `[database2].[anothertable]` when any new record insert in `[database1].[mytable]` without losing any single data.

And there are a approx 70/100 records inserted every second into `[database1].[mytable]`. I want to move that data and have to do some calculation and then insert into `[database2].[anothertable]`.

I have tried triggers and stored procedures as well but it take too much database memory though sometime my db hangs when there are concurrent user try to connect.

So I have read and come up with solution like SQL Server service broker and `SqlDependency` with a C# application.

My questions is: can I rely on SQL Server service broker or `SqlDependency` to achieve this? Because I do not want to lost/drop my any data as this are very important data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: "Out of extended support" doesn't fully convey things: they are **end of life**. This means they don't get any new patches... _not even critical security updates!_ It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using this version.

Comment: Ok but if use another sql version then it will provide limitation on db size(Max 1 Gb/database I guess) . And i have license of this sql server.

Comment: I need at least 5GB/database. I have multiple database.

Comment: SQL Server 2019 Express Edition is free, and supports 10GB databases, and advanced compression.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15#Cross-BoxScaleLimits